# how to get a different result set from the same column in one table

Tags: sql, subquery

i have a column in one table where i want to use it with two different where conditions.

This is what i have

```
select t.Answer,
(select top 1 t2.Answer
FROM dbo.table1 t2
INNER JOIN dbo.qa
ON q.QuestionActionID = qa.QuestionActionID
INNER JOIN dbo.Questions
ON Questions.QuestionID = qa.QuestionID
INNER JOIN dbo.Visits
ON Visits.VisitID = q.VisitID

Where

Questions.QuestionID = 4583 
and v.ID = 47543

and qa.TypeID = 3 // equals
and V.UserID='test'

) as comments
FROM dbo.table1 t
INNER JOIN dbo.qa
ON t.QuestionActionID = qa.QuestionActionID
INNER JOIN dbo.Questions
ON Questions.QuestionID = qa.QuestionID
INNER JOIN dbo.Visits v
ON V.VisitID = t.VisitID
Where
Questions.QuestionID = 4583 
and V.ID = 47543
and V.UserID='test'
and  qa.TypeID <> 3 //does not equal
```

which gives the following output

```
Answer  | comment
12      | cup
25      | cup
```

as you can see its adding "cup" to all of the comments because i said "Top 1".
Basically my sub query has a different type id value and my primary query has a not equal to type id value.

My question is how do i get my sub query to return more than 1 value so that it matches the corresponding row.

Note i can not use UNION ( this would have worked) because this query ends up been plugged into a larger query

Comment: Please provide the DMBS where you are running this query.

Comment: You have somehow mutilated the query. What is table q? What is table v?

Comment: Please add sample data so that we can understand what you are trying to achieve.